# Stack overflow error in return statement

Tags: java, stack-overflow

Getting a stack overflow error when i submit to canvas but it runs fine in Visual Studio Code, anyone know what the issue is?

Here is the error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StackOverflowError
    at Phi.gcd(Phi.java:14
```

Here is the assignment:

> Euler's totient function, otherwise known as φ(n), measures the number
>   of positive integers relatively prime to n that are less than n. Two
>   numbers are relatively prime if their gcd is 1. For example: φ(9) = 6
>   because 1, 2, 4, 5, 7, and 8 are relatively prime to 9. More
>   information about Euler's totient function can be found at this Wiki
>   page.
>
> ```
> n Relatively Prime    φ(n)
> 2 1   1
> 3 1,2 2
> 4 1,3 2
> 5 1,2,3,4 4
> 6 1,5 2
> 7 1,2,3,4,5,6 6
> 8 1,3,5,7 4
> 9 1,2,4,5,7,8 6
> 10    1,3,7,9 4
> ```
>
> Write a function int `phi(int n)` that takes an integer `n` as an input
>   and returns φ(n), and a `main()` that prompts a user for an integer `i`,
>   calls the function φ(i), and prints the result. The upper limit for
>   the input `i` is 250000.
>
> The closed form formula for computing φ(n) is:   where p1, p2, ..., pm
>   are prime numbers that divide the number n.
>
> The output of your program should look and function like the examples
>   shown below.
>
> ```
> Enter a positive integer n: 8
> Phi(n): 4
> ```

And here is my code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Phi {

    static int gcd(int a, int b)
    {
        if (a == 0 || b == 0)
            return 0;

        if (a == b)
            return a;

        if (a > b)
            return gcd(a-b, b);
        return gcd(a, b-a);
    }

    static int phi(int n) {
        int count=0;
        for(int i = 1; i < n; ++i) {
            if(gcd(n, i) == 1) {
                count++;
            }
        }
        return count;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Enter a positive integer n: ");;
        int n = in.nextInt();
        System.out.printf("Phi(%d): %d\n", n, phi(n));
    }

}
```

Comment: This is line 14 by the way:    return gcd(a-b, b);

Comment: What input are you passing, when you get the error?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is because your recursive GCD method converges to the value of GCD very slowly. For example, if you pass 250000 and 1, your method would use 250000 stack frames, more than most JVMs would allocate for you.

One solution is to rewrite Euclid's GCD algorithm with iterations. Another solution is to use a faster algorithm:

```
int gcd(int a, int b) {
    return (b != 0) ? gcd(b, a % b) : a;
}
```

Comment: Im trying to figure out what to replace with your algorithm @dasblinkenlight, any help? could you make an edit on the code itself?

Comment: @JediObiJohn This is a replacement for your `static int gcd` method, which gives you stack overflow. Replace its body with the `return` line.